# Why sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier and sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier don't accept categorial input variables?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Decision Tree algorithms and RandomForest algorithms work naturally with categorical data (input and output). Why the implementations sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier and sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier can not handle categorical input data?

Comment: All of scikit-learn has been designed to only accept numerical inputs. Check out the [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) to transform your categorical levels into dummy features that can be modeled over

Comment: What exactly is your question and the expected answer? A design/engineering explanation of their rationale?

Answer (score -2):

Scikit-learn relies heavily on Numpy/Scipy, which works natively with numeric data. We need to convert each text category to numbers in order for algorithm to process them using mathematical equations. In case with DecisionTree in order to choose a node with Minimum Gini Impurity values, we should generalize them into categories with multiple levels.

**It is important to note, that these details depend on the specific implementation. R, for instance, provides factors to represent categorical data which is represented by integers under the hood in R's memory.**
This fact also raises questions concerning this algorithm's 'space complexity'. Referencing to documentation, *in earlier versions of R, storing character data as a factor was more space efficient if there is even a small proportion of repeats. However, identical character strings now share storage, so the difference is small in most cases. (Integer values are stored in 4 bytes whereas each reference to a character string needs a pointer of 4 or 8 bytes.)*

Comment: The assertion that "*Machines understand numbers, not text*" is not applicable here; neither it explains why in other decision tree implementations (most notably in R) categorical features can be processed directly and without special preprocessing (such as one-hot encoding). Arguably, OP here asks about the specific *design choice* for scikit-learn.

Comment: well, I should have clarified, that these details depend on concrete implementation. R provides factors to represent categorical data which is represented by integers under the hood in R's memory.